# How connect to multiple databases in PHP using Database Class or like MVC pattern?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, database-connection

I want my application to simultaneously connect to multiple databases. This is my current DB configuration:

```
'database_config' => array(
'db1' =>array( 
    'host_name' => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'dbname'    => 'database1',
    'dbprefix'  => '',
    'dbtype'    => 'mysql'

)
,'db2' => array(
    'host_name' => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'dbname'    => 'test',
    'dbprefix'  => '',
    'dbtype'    => 'mysql'

)  
);
```

Now I am including this file and I want to connect database if Multiple database connection given as array in configuration file else connect with the first database given in db configuration file.

I wrote my own coding structure. Same like codeigniter, cakephp or yii framework style I want to connect with multiple database in a go and want to access the db with same name which is given in configuration file.

I tried loop if multiple config but after connecting if I want to access database then its shows error because The table which I want to access and selecting data from it its available only in first DB but not exists in second database. So If anyone have better solution for this with oops style, please give me solution.  It will be helpful.

With Thanks & regards, 
Sanjay Dey

Comment: I tried to translate your question in english , but failed... What is "multiple database"? You are using it as if it some sort of title? Why are you making some sort of loop? And how is it all related to missing tables?

Comment: It is impossible to establish connection to multiple databases and treat them as if it was a single DB, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Teresko, I have given my array of database configuration above. I want to connect database. If Multiple database connection string given then it have connect with multiple database else the first default database it should connect as Like MVC framework Codeigniter/cake php You can see. If You have any solution provide it. Since I am trying to select data with db object $this->db->select(); so script taking the second connection and trying to execute the query.My table in which i am executing query it is in 1st db not exists in 2nd db.So Its shows Error. Provide some solution for multiple db

Comment: of words sentence the matters order in.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience in codeigniter we use this configuration to define DB and connect to each one we want

```
$active_group = "forum";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['forum']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['forum']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['forum']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['forum']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['forum']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['forum']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

/* TEST SITE */
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

**Your active db will be the one you defined LAST.**

and when we need it

```
$this->db_forum = $this->CI->load->database('forum', TRUE);
```

Access dbase 1 with $this->db and dbase 2 with $this->db_forum (or whatever you called it).

Comment: <b>HI ! Reza Marefaty,</b> You are exactly right. I want to achieve same functionality. But I am not using any framework to achieve this. I wrote my own coding structure. Same like codeigniter, cakephp or yii framework style I want to connect with multiple database in a go and want to access the db with same name which is given in configuration file. If you have any solution please do post. It will be helpful for me and others too.                                                                      With Regards, Sanjay Dey

Comment: If you are not using cakephp, then why is question tagged with it ?

Comment: Its because I want to achive same like Cake php/ yii / Codeigniter. So I tagged. If You have any kind of solution then provide please.

Comment: Wow Perfect.. You save my day dude. Thank you so much